# Insering values into table/showing duplicates

Tags: ms-access, vba

When Im inserting a value from Form in the Table, first value in the table always is updated with the listed one in the  table field.
Im using below code:
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
Private Sub Command114_Click()



If (Me.VehicleNumber = "" Or Me.vMake = "" Or Me.vModel = "") Then
MsgBox "Please fill required fields", vbInformation, "Information"
Else

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Vehicles]([VehicleNumber], [Make], [Model], [PurchasedMiles], [PurchasePrice], [PurchaseLocation], [PurchaseDate], [VehicleNotes])" & _
"VALUES ('" & Me.vVehicleNumber & "', '" & Me.vMake & "', '" & Me.vModel & "', '" & Me.vPurchasedMiles & "', '" & Me.vPurchasePrice & "', '" & Me.vPurchaseLocation & "', '" & Me.vPurchaseDate & "', '" & Me.vVehicleNotes & "')"

MsgBox "Vehicle Added", vbInformation, "Information"

End If


End Sub
```

[image]
please check the picture.

THANKS :D

Comment: Are you trying to say, when you insert a new row, previously inserted rows are updated?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue

Comment: OK, let's try to be more specific. When, using the Form, you created the row with id=28, the row with id=24 were updated. Affected fields were the fields that you marked on the image. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the ID Field is Auto Number, and when Im adding record the ID(24) always is updated, sa,e like new added value

Answer (score 1):

I think your form is bounded and everytime when you are entering any data you are modifying exiting data.

If you want to insert manually set the form's Record source value to be empty.

```
goto forms's property > Data section> Record Source > delete any    entry there
```

Alternatively let the form to be bounded. and use the new record function to add new record. you don't even need the manual insert function. Access will automatically save it for you.

Comment: Is there a problem that I have added fields from "Add Existing Fields"?   I have created from beginning without using Add Existing Fields and now is OK

Comment: add exisiting field will only be available if your form is bounded.. again you don't need manual insertion command for that. unbound the form if you want to perform manual insertion. and make it answer if its solved